# Swift SpriteKit: Running two SKActions forever separately

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I am new to Swift and SpriteKit, and I have a small problem. I would like to spawn enemies once per second, while moving the player slightly once per frame. So I tried to create two separate SKActions. This is my code:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(
                addEnemy
            ),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)
        ])
    ))

runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
    SKAction.runBlock(
        movePlayer
    )
))
```

But when I run the above, neither action(s) happen. How would I fix this?

Comment: They shouldn't affect each other. Have you tried using NSTimer instead of `runAction` instead?

Comment: My guess is that either this code is never called, or that the object these are called on are never allocated or are deallocated early.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. Perhaps posting `addEnemy` and `movePlayer` would be helpful. Did you try adding a breakpoint in one of these functions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `self.addEnemy()` & `self.movePlayer()`

And just for the Eye, I would write the code like that:

```
var waitE = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
var runE = SKAction.runBlock{
self.addEnemy()
}

var runP = SKAction.runBlock{
    self.movePlayer()
} 

var repeatMovingPlayer = SKAction.repeatActionForever(runP)
var EnemySeqence = SKAction.seqence([waitE, runE])
var repeatAddingEnemy = SKAction.repeatActionForever(EnemySeqence)

self.runAction(repeatAddingEnemy)
self.runAction(repeatMovingPlayer)
```